# macOS Sierra + MacBook Pro 15'' + 3 external monitors = freeze

Tags: macos, multiple-monitors, macbook-pro-retina

This setup worked fine with El Capitan (2 Thunderbolts->HDMI + 1 HDMI = 3 Monitors). Once updated to macOS Sierra - as soon as I plug in 3rd monitor (no matter what order) - it freezes entire system.

MacBook Pro 15 (Retina, Mid 2012)

Anyone else had similar issue ?
Anyone is running such setup fine ?

Safe boot mode does not help.

Comment: See the comment made by @MEWeas. This workaround fixes the problem, until Apple get it resolved

Comment: @MrPaulDriver - that workaround works - but unfortunately I would like to have Mac screen as well. Was hoping for 10.12.1 to solve the issue - but not luck after updating :(

Comment: I bought HDMI->DVI cable and all works fine - I have 4 monitors running (3 external) as before :)

Comment: Seems to be fixed in 10.12.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same problem. I have plugged in one screen via HDMI on the right and one Screen via Thunderbolt dock on the left.

When I plugin the third screen via DisplayPort to HDMI adapter the Mac freezes and I can only restart after I unplugged the third screen.

MBP Retina Mid 2012.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. You just saved me a lot of time on trying if fresh install solves the issue and then restoring back from Time Machine to current state :)

Answer (score 2):

So after some more trial and error this is what seems to work for me for now and seems stable.  This will only work if you have 3 external monitors (one HDMI, 2 thunderbolts) and you keep your MBP shut.

1. Plug in one HDMI and one thunderbolt and boot while the laptop is open.
2. Once booted, close your laptop and wait for the screens to refresh.
3. Once the screens are refreshed, plug in the 2nd thunderbolt monitor.

From there your three monitors should be working.  The only ting is that you can't open your MBP unless you unplug the last thunderbolt connected monitor.  I hope that Apple fixes this, it's a big pain.

Comment: Unfortunately this isn't working for me -- I can get ANY two-monitor subset of my three to work.  When I unplug one of the working monitors, the previously non-working one springs to life, and then re-plugging the one I just took out has no effect.  I can repeat this all day, hopping from this two-monitor configuration to that two-monitor configuration, but I cannot get all three to run.